# GridLayout with TextView creating extra margins

Tags: android, margin, android-gridlayout

I am attempting to create a GridLayout that should Scroll Horizontally, and display a variety of TextView's using the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:columnCount="8">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test goes onto two lines"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </GridLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me why it displays like this when one TextView has text that goes over two lines?

[image]

If the text does not go over two lines, it renders fine.

[image]

Comment: you are hardcoding width and heigh! you should use weight system to devide weight among the items, and you also have to see that your items are not equal in margins from each other !

Comment: Thanks, but the margins are equal, they are the same for every item. The size is hard coded because it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set `android:layout_gravity="top"` in the TextView to achieve what I wanted.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Test with some text"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```

[image]